# Python3.6 threading is not slow as expected on Windows (CPython interpreter)

Tags: python, windows, python-multithreading, cpython, gil

I wrote some code to test the affect of GIL to multithreaded application with python 3.6 on Windows (8 cores). It was a simple CPU-bound task. The expectation is that the single threaded version is faster than the multithreaded one but the reality is the other way around. Please help me explain. Thank you.

```
import time
import concurrent.futures

NUMBERS = [5000000 + x for x in range(20)]

def cpu_bound(number):
    return sum(i * i for i in range(number))


def find_sums(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        cpu_bound(number)
        

def find_sums_threading(numbers):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
        executor.map(cpu_bound, numbers)


def run():
    start_time = time.time()
    find_sums(NUMBERS)
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"Duration {duration} seconds")


def run_threading():
    start_time = time.time()
    find_sums_threading(NUMBERS)
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"Duration {duration} seconds")


run()
run_threading()
```

Here is the running result:

```
Interpreter:  CPython
Single threaded: 15.699885129928589 seconds
Threading: 12.54316520690918 seconds
```

Comment: If a CPU bound task could not be speed up with multiprocessing, what can?

Comment: @ead, but it is using ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: @ead CPython implementation has Global Intepreter Lock which allows only 1 thread to execute at a time. So the expectation is the multithreaded version is slower because of the overhead of creating threads and locking and context switching.

Comment: what result are you *seeing*? Why wouldn't you post the output?

Comment: That's an over simplification of what the GIL does.  It doesn't completely block parallel threads from running, just slows them down more than is ideal.

Comment: @MarkRansom could you elaborate, it is my understanding that only one thread will be allowed to execute python bytecode at a time. Perhaps the `sum` implementation releases the GIL?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm not well versed on the details of the GIL, but I didn't think it was a pure lock-and-hold implementation - the GIL gets released quite often.  Python does seem to be the poster child for [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) though.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'll update my question

Answer (score 0):

In a multithreaded Python program, all the threads use a single CPU.  All the threads share the same address space, which means that all the threads can access the same set of objects.  Splitting a CPU-bound program across several threads will *not* result in a performance improvement because no additional CPU cycles have been brought into play.  Performance will get slightly worse because of the overhead involved in task switching.

In a multiprocessing Python program, child processes use other CPU cores if they are available.  Different process do not share an address space, which means that special methods must be used to pass data from one process to another.  This data-passing is an overhead for a multiprocessing application, but it is often the case that splitting a CPU-bound program across multiple processes will improve performance.  More than one CPU core means more computing power is available to the program.

Python supports both mechanisms in its standard library, under the title of "Concurrent Execution."

Comment: You are incorrect, multi-threading can use multiple cores if they are available.  There would be no point to it if you couldn't.

Comment: I'm not sure how this address the question being asked.

Comment: Well, the question asked for an explanation of why threading didn't improve the performance of a CPU-bound program.  And the first comment was that if threading didn't improve performance, then what does?  This is what I attempted to answer.  Perhaps I didn't interpret the question correctly.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Sorry for not posting the running result. I'll update my question. But the threading version did improve the performance of the cpu-bound program so I need an explanation.